# NSFetchedResultsController and NSPredicate and a section name

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have core data model with two entities that have a many-to-many relationship with each other.

Eg,

```
Conference <<---->> Speaker
```

A conference can have many speakers, and One speaker can be at many conferences.

Im trying to use NSFetchedResultsController the main entity for fetchRequest is the **Speaker**.

While it does list all speakers alright, but Im trying to get the section as  the "Conference" name and list all speakers within that section. I want it so that the name "John" as speaker would appear in two sections. Which implies that he's a speaker at two conferences.

This is the sectionNameKeyPath i'm using:  `@"conferences.Name"`

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"conferences.Name"  cacheName:@"fCache"] autorelease];
```

It kinda doesn't work, i get `{TedEx}`  as the section title when i use `[sectionInfo name]`.

The other problem is that If I One speaker appears in one section, (conference), it wont appear in the other section (even if that section(conference) has that speaker object).

This is potentially because,  I get the sectionName as a set of combined Conferences. `TedEx, SXSW` as a single section.

Some how the goal should be to single out the sectionNameKeypath to fetch only ONE Conference and list all speakers within each. Perhaps i should set some kind of a predicate?

Im  kinda in a bind here, is the approach a problem? I've read about Predicates but its kinda hard to grasp if your new to core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little different from the way you are thinking of doing it, and I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish it with a FRC & sectionNameKeyPath like you want to or not, but perhaps this will work:

1. Instead of fetching Speakers, just do a normal `NSFetchRequest` to get
   an `NSArray` called `conferences`.  You could have this sorted by
   conferenceName or date or whatever you need.
2. Then for your table view set the number of sections to the `[conferences count]`.
3. For number of rows in each section get the Conference object for that section `[conferences objectAtIndex:section]`, and return the speakers count of that Conference.
4. To populate the cell data, just get the Speaker object by called: `[[conferences objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: thanks for the answer Mark, although i was asking specifically for NSFetchedResultsController.. i preferred that cuz any changes would reflect without any effort in the table where as in i'd have to handle everything in fetch request. But i do realize theres no way of doing it in NSFetchResultsController